# Use v-if with deep property object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I want to check if the property url is set on the item object, if it's not there I want to display a placeholder image. Something like this:

```
        <img
          v-if="item.relationships.main_image.attributes.url"
          :src="item.relationships.main_image.attributes.url"
          :alt="item.attributes.name"
          class="h-full w-full"
        />
        <img v-else :src="require('@/assets/placeholder.png')" alt=""/>
```

The problem is that my item object may not have any properties, as backend only send those properties if there is actually an image linked to the item.

How can i check if an object has that deep property?

```js
Error given: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'attributes')
```

Comment: [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify this and get rid of this extra img tag. Also if any of item object properties can be `null` you can use optional chaining (e.g. `item?.relationships...`).

I don't know which property can and cannot be `null`, so lets assume the worst case scenario:

```
<img :src="item?.relationships?.main_image?.attributes?.url || require('@/assets/placeholder.png')"
     :alt="item?.attributes?.name || 'placeholder'"
     class="h-full w-full"/>
```